# Trouble understanding torsion

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, projective-module

I'm reading [this](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ehrm/palestine/weibel/06-group_homology_and_cohomology.pdf) paper. In definition 6.1.2 it is mentioned that $H_n(G;A) \cong \text{Tor}_n^{\mathbb{Z}G}(\mathbb{Z}, A)$ (for all $n=0, 1, 2, ...$). What exactly is meant by the right-hand side? I'm familiar with torsion in other contexts, but I'm not sure how to interpret the superscript $\mathbb{Z}G$.

Comment: It refers to the Tor functor (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_functor). The relationship to torsion is somewhat indirect: when computing Tor over $\mathbb{Z}$ we have that $\text{Tor}_1^{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}, A)$ computes the torsion subgroup of $A$.